# While loop and MySql Update

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, connection

I'm having issues with my `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){`. It is meant to load through all the users and it checks if anything about their profile needs to be updated. It then does an `update` to the database. The problem is if anything is updated, it will update any person with an ID greater than them(Anyone next on the while loop it will give them the same database values). I try and close the connection at the end of the loop, but it permanently disconnects and doesn't finish the loop.
Update.php:

```
            require_once('../../mysqli_connect.php');
        $query = "SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(birthdate) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(birthdate, 5)) as age, datediff(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, date_rank) AS tig, id_member, first_name, last_name, birthdate, date_join, date_rank, points,
        njp, mos, rank, qual, real_name, billet FROM smf_members";

        $response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if($response){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){

        *CODE EMMITED*    

        $query2 = "UPDATE smf_members SET real_name='$real_name', rank='$rank', date_rank='$date_rank', default_rank='$default_rank', rank_cap='$rank_cap' WHERE id_member='$id_member'"; 
        $response2 = @mysqli_query($dbc2, $query2);

        } 
        } else {

        echo "Couldn't issue database query<br />";

        echo mysqli_error($dbc);

        }

        // Close connection to the database
        mysqli_close($dbc);

         ?>
```

mysqli_connect.php:

```
<?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'Username');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'Password');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'Database Name');


$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .
mysqli_connect_error());

$dbc2 = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .
mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

I fixed it by redefining the varibles at the begining of the loop. Here is the fixed index.php:

```
    <?php

                        require_once('../../mysqli_connect.php');
                    $query = "SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(birthdate) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(birthdate, 5)) as age, datediff(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, date_rank) AS tig, id_member, first_name, last_name, birthdate, date_join, date_rank, points,
                    njp, mos, rank, qual, real_name, billet FROM smf_members";

                    $response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
                    if($response){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
                    //Redefine Database
$id_member = $row["id_member"];
$age = $row["age"];
$tig = $row["tig"];
$first_name = $row["first_name"];
$last_name = $row["last_name"];
$birthdate = $row["birthdate"];
$date_join = $row["date_join"];
$date_rank = $row["date_rank"];
$points = $row["points"];
$njp = $row["njp"];
$mos = $row["mos"];
$rank = $row["rank"];
$qual = $row["qual"];
$real_name = $row["real_name"];
$billet = $row["billet"];
$rank_cap = $row["rank_cap"];
$default_rank = $row["default_rank"];    
                    *CODE EMMITED*    

                    $query2 = "UPDATE smf_members SET real_name='$real_name', rank='$rank', date_rank='$date_rank', default_rank='$default_rank', rank_cap='$rank_cap' WHERE id_member='$id_member'"; 
                    $response2 = @mysqli_query($dbc2, $query2);

                    } 
                    } else {

                    echo "Couldn't issue database query<br />";

                    echo mysqli_error($dbc);

                    }

                    // Close connection to the database
                    mysqli_close($dbc);

                     ?>
```

Comment: I just redefined the varibles right after the while loop started and it fixed it.: `$id_member = $row["id_member"];
$age = $row["age"];
$tig = $row["tig"];
$first_name = $row["first_name"];
$last_name = $row["last_name"];
$birthdate = $row["birthdate"];
$date_join = $row["date_join"];
$date_rank = $row["date_rank"];
$points = $row["points"];
$njp = $row["njp"];
$mos = $row["mos"];
$rank = $row["rank"];
$qual = $row["qual"];
$real_name = $row["real_name"];
$billet = $row["billet"];
$rank_cap = $row["rank_cap"];
$default_rank = $row["default_rank"];`